# GT5: How to drift?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I've been trying out the drifting in Gran Turismo 5 and I'm finding it ridiculously hard to get a good drift going. Does anyone have any tips or hints on how to play this game mode?

I'm using stick controls and an automatic gearbox, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://www.ehow.com/video_4936303_drift-gran-turismo-5-cars.html?ref=Track2&utm_source=ask) contains videos of someone drifting different cars in GT5 in the series "How to Drift Gran Turismo 5 Cars".

If you find this answer useless( which I hope you don't ), then please tell me.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need hard and soft tires just go with comfort soft for all 4 wheels.  Two techniques you can use is power over or feint.  With AWD you'll find it easier with Feint.  Coming to a corner you'll want to go a little faster than normal controlling your throttle turn slightly to the opposite direction this will shift the weight of the car towards the corner then turn back into the corner hard will shift the weight to the opposite with more force then tap brake then gas softly then countersteer if needed.  Power over is almost the same but you don't weight shift or brake.  Just punch the gas when you turn into the corner and then countersteer.

Answer (score 3):

You need soft tires on the front and hard tires on the back, and then you need to tune the suspension. The best tune settings are unique for each car. After this, make sure you are driving in manual, because automatic basically corrects the drift and makes you spin out.

Answer (score 0):

I drift AT with a controller. Gearbox is irrelevant I promise. With a properly tuned LSD the car will prefer to maintain high RPMs when all the driving aids are turned off. Veteran secret.

My recommended button mappings for drifting are Gas(R2) Brakes(L2) E-brake(x or circle) Steering(Left Stick).

Most important tunings: LSD (Acc:60 or maxed, Torque:60 or maxed, Braking:5 or minimized), Suspension (Spring rate and toe angles being most important), Tires (DON'T MIX-MATCH TIRES and don't go higher than Sports Hard. I only use Sports Hard on cars with more than 700BHP)

Power over and Feint techniques are great techniques. Ripping the e-brake helps if you're having trouble drifting long MR vehicles.

Try to use light vehicles... 1400 Kg or less, although I've drifted a Toyota Tacoma and a GT-R just fine.

Turn off ALL of the driving aids. Every single one. If you're using a controller have your sensitivity between 1 and 3. I use 1 personally but 3 gives you "prettier" slides because of the dramatic over-corrections.

Experiment with different drive cameras. You drift differently when your perception of the road changes. I drift best with the "over the hood" view.

After that it's all practice and helpful tips from people who don't suck. Inbox me anytime on PSN. l2oI that's a lower-case "L" the number "2" lower-case "O" and capital "I"

Answer (score 0):

Drive very fast(about usually 200+mph).Turn the traction control and ABS(anti lock braking system,it prevents spinning out). Set downforce to minimal or even if possible,remove spoiler.,use comfort hard  at the back and sport hard in the front if not you will spin out.Go into a wet track and if your car is 4 wheel drive,set the torque machine thingy to 10:90(10 in the front,90 and the back). Or if it's front wheel drive(get rid of it), set LSD to 60 torque and 60 acceleration to increase understeer. Once that's done,drive fast and brake (do not stop accelerating,keep pressing the acceleration button) and steer hard.( either you will drift or you will spin out but that's better than driving normally).Oh and set stability control to off. And make sure your car is very light, I prefer using a MP4-12c with 800+ bhp with no spoiler added. And if you are about to spin out,steer the opposite direction so that the rear does not stick out too much,causing you to spin out,so control the drift.